# How to use partition in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a table of employees with their name, dept and salary.
[See here](https://ibb.co/7Q3bVb2)

I want to fetch 2 highest salary employees from every dept

This is how I achieved in MySql,

```
select dept, name, salary from ( 
        select dept, name, salary,
        row_number() over (
                partition by dept 
                order by salary desc
            ) rn
        from 
        employees as T
    )as T
    where T.rn < 2;
```

How would I write this with
Laravel **Eloquent** or Query Builder (Without using raw)?

Comment: Do you have an Employee model set up? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I do. Its just a basic Model that takes all the values.

Comment: I am asking this after a very exhaustive search. I am unable to find anything like PARTITION BY in Laravel Eloquent or Query Builder.

Comment: I believe there must be a function something like map or filter that can be used to achieve that?